# Post processing Three JS

Tags: javascript, three.js, post-processing

I have a problem with the three js post processing. I chose the glitchpass effect. So i import all the libraries etc but the effect doesn't work. Nothing happened but there are no errors in the console.

```
 this.renderer = renderer;
    this.composer = new THREE.EffectComposer( renderer );
    this.composer.addPass( new THREE.RenderPass( this, camera ) );

    this.glitchPass = new THREE.GlitchPass();
    this.glitchPass.renderToScreen = true;
   // this.giltchPass.goWild = true;
    this.composer.addPass( this.glitchPass );
```

And the animate loop :

```
  this.composer.render();
```

I have no idea why the code doesn't work. So i put the same code directly into an html file (test.html)

It is the same code but that's work (without inherit and this).

Have u any ideas ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This line of your code:

```
this.composer.addPass( new THREE.RenderPass( this, camera ) );
```

should be:

```
this.composer.addPass( new THREE.RenderPass( scene, camera ) );
```

Comment: I forget to precise that, my class inherit from THREE.scene , its for that i did this